# Separate 1024 width devices

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I am developing an Android app that is causing me problems with devices that have 1024 as their width dimension. I have tried creating a layout folder layout-w1024 and layout-mdpi-sw1024dp; but the device uses the layout-mdpi folder instead. I am using 15 as the minimum android version.

Is there any other way using which I can separate 1024 devices?

Comment: The device is a 1024 by ...? the correct name for mdpi tablet layout folders is layout-swXYZdp-mdpi where XYZ is the MINIMUM WIDTH (so: 1024*600 => XYZ is 600, not 1024)

Comment: I have folder with sw600dp-mdpi and sw768dp-mdpi; but the layout files are still taken from the layout-mdpi folder. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: did you try the -land and -port variations? Because I the default is -port (so it will default to the mdpi folder, if not found), while instead I guess you are using it mostly in -land orientation.

Comment: Yes I am using landscape. Actually my complete folder names are layout-sw600dp-land-mdpi and layout-sw768dp-land-mdpi. Even though this fits the description of the device well, the layout is still not taken from these folders.

Comment: Really funny. So, my last resort would be, following the android developer's word: `even combine the w<N>dp and h<N>dp qualifiers` something like: `layout-w1024dp-h600dp-mdpi-land`. And the same for h = 768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically if it's suitable for your project, something like this would call a different layout depending on the dimensions of the screen. This has some limitations though since it can only be called from an Activity (shouldn't be a problem in your case) and if you have problems with layouts all over your application it may not be very scalable.

The conditional `width == 1024` should probably be replaced with something greater than or more specific, you'll need to play with this for a while to make it work. You should also account for the height of the screen, not only the width.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
```

Or if you want it in pixels instead:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

And then:

```
//Depending on the width, set one layout or anotherone
setContentView(width == 1024?R.layout.for1024:R.layout.normal);
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

Comment: I just tried this code and size.x gives me 455 instead of 1024 ? Do I need to do some calculations ? I'm sorry I'm new to all of this.